# How to paginate by date with Django?

Tags: mysql, django, pagination

I looked up how to use the Django's built-in pagination and it doesn't look very scalable for certain cases. In my case, I am climbing a log table so what I wanted to do was something like this:

```
Page 1:
SELECT ... FROM log WHERE date > '2012-11-04 00:00:00' LIMIT 10;
Page 2:
SELECT ... FROM log WHERE date > '#LAST_VALUE_FROM_PAGE_1' LIMIT 10;
Page 3:
SELECT ... FROM log WHERE date > '#LAST_VALUE_FROM_PAGE_2' LIMIT 10;
...
```

In other words, I want to climb an index instead of grabbing the entire result-set and iterating on that. Assuming date is indexed, this should keep things really efficient while still producing mostly the same results since I'm always ordering by date anyway.

What I was curious about was if this has already been done and a modular way, much like how Django's built-in pagination methods worked or if I'll need to go it alone and write my own method?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is cached queryset across multiple requests. There are few modules that can be used for that.

Couple of them are:

- [SmartCachingQuerySet](http://jeffelmore.org/2010/09/25/smarter-caching-of-django-querysets/)
- [The QuerySet Cache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/queryset_cache.html)

Although, personally I haven't used any so don't have first hand experience.